# Switching from standalone to beamer gives an error

Tags: beamer, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to modify the below code and use it in beamer instead of standalone, however, when I switch the document class to beamer I get an error "illegal parameter number..this part of the code is giving the error

```
  \newcommand{\positionXOnEl}[3]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}%
      {\figYOrigin+#2*%
      \figBEll*((1-#3^2/\figAEll^2)^2)^(0.25)}}
  \newcommand{\positionYOnEl}[3]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}%
      {#2*((\figBEll^2-\figYOrigin^2+2*\figYOrigin*#3-#3^2)^2)^(0.25)*(\figAEll/\figBEll)}}
```

although it is only a new command.

```
 %\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\documentclass[9pt,aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
% !TEX root = ../main.tex
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{100}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,tdplot_main_coords]
  % DEFINITIONS
  % figOmegaRotation : Value for the Omega angle
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\figOmega}{33}
  % figIRotation : value for inclination of the orbital plane
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\figIRotation}{30}
  % \figAEll : minimum value for ellipse
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\figAEll}{2.5}
  % \figBEll : minimum value for ellipse
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\figBEll}{3}
  % figYOrigin : focus of the ellipse with 2.5 and 3
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\figYOrigin}{sqrt(\figBEll^2 - \figAEll^2)}
    % sqrt(b^2 - a^2)

  % COMMANDS
  % \positionOnEl{\storing}{\quadrant}{\x}
  % Saves into \storing the position \y on the ellipse
  % specified by \figAEll and \figBEll. \quadrant should help
  % in defining the quadrant (must be +1 or -1)
  \newcommand{\positionXOnEl}[3]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}%
      {\figYOrigin+#2*%
      \figBEll*((1-#3^2/\figAEll^2)^2)^(0.25)}}
  \newcommand{\positionYOnEl}[3]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}%
      {#2*((\figBEll^2-\figYOrigin^2+2*\figYOrigin*#3-#3^2)^2)^(0.25)*(\figAEll/\figBEll)}}



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Delete all your auxiliary files and try compiling again.

Comment: try now please with the minimized one.

Comment: Probably some fragile macro (instead of catcode) issue. Adding `[fragile]` works.

Comment: yes, it solved the problem. Thanks